# Computing averages by groups with R

Tags: r

I have data that I would like to compute some statistics with.
The data is organized in such a way that I have a value corresponding to each 3-element tuple
Something like

```
(P1,M1,R1,V1)
(P1,M1,R2,V2)
(P1,M2,R1,V1)
...
```

here P1, M1, and R1 are not numeric but V1 and V2 are.
Right now I have the data in a csv file, x2.cvs as follows:

```
P,M,R,V
P1,M1,R1,V1
P1,M1,R2,V2
...
```

I read the data using

```
d = read.table("x2.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

but after that I don't know what to do to process the data.

I would like to start by computing simple information like:
what is the average for each element of P (so the average would be over all elements
of M and R), or for each pair of elements of {P,M} (so the average here would be over the elements of R.

Next I would like to do a little bit more complicated things like compute how many elements of P1 are bigger than some specified value.

Comment: try the function BASIC. It gives you a really basic info, among that the means...

Comment: I'd also add ... look for an R tutorial, because this is really basic stuff, so it's not really worth a large answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a start, with `data.table`, `plyr` and base functions, there are so many other ways...

First, some example data...

```
dput(examp)
structure(list(P = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("P1", 
"P2"), class = "factor"), M = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("M1", 
"M2"), class = "factor"), R = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("R1", 
"R2"), class = "factor"), V = c(23, 49, 24, 29)), .Names = c("P", 
"M", "R", "V"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
#
# to give something like what you have...
#
examp
   P  M  R  V
1 P1 M1 R1 23
2 P1 M1 R2 49
3 P1 M2 R1 24
4 P2 M2 R1 29
```

Here is one way using `data.table`. If your data object is very big, you'll find the `data.table` package to be very fast, documentation is also excellent: http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-intro.pdf

```
# What is the average of each element of P?
library(data.table)
examp.dt <- data.table(examp)
setkey(examp.dt,P)
examp.dt[,mean(V),by=P]
      P V1
[1,] P1 32
[2,] P2 29
#
```

And another using `plyr`

```
# What is the average of each element of P?
library(plyr)
ddply(examp, "P", function(df)mean(df$V))
P V1
1 P1 32
2 P2 29
```

And another using base R

```
# What is the average of each element of P?
# for example using the by() function,  tapply() would be similar
with(examp, by(examp, P, mean))
P: P1
P  M  R  V 
NA NA NA 32 
------------------------------------------------- 
P: P2
P  M  R  V 
NA NA NA 29
#
# What is the average of each element of R? 
with(examp, by(examp, R, mean))
R: R1
P        M        R        V 
NA       NA       NA 25.33333 
----------------------------------------------
R: R2
P  M  R  V 
NA NA NA 49 
#
# the same, using tapply
with(examp, tapply(V, R, mean)
  R1       R2 
25.33333 49.00000
```

And for your last question,  how many elements of P1 are bigger than some specified value, we can use `subset` like so:

```
# how many elements of P1 are greater than 20?
nrow(subset(examp, examp$P=="P1" & examp$V>20))
[1] 3
```

Or even just `[` for the same result with less typing:

```
nrow(examp[examp$P=="P1" & examp$V>20,])
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 5):

The `aggregate` function is probably the easiest to use for what you are asking:

1) *what is the average for each element of P*?

```
aggregate(formula = V ~ P, data = d, FUN = mean)
```

2) *or for each pair of elements of {P,M}*?

```
aggregate(formula = V ~ M + R, data = d, FUN = mean)
```

3) *how many elements of P1 are bigger than some specified value*?

```
aggregate(formula = V ~ P, data = d, FUN = function(x)sum(x > 10))
```