# How to get statistics from a sub-set of factors?

Tags: r

Using `by` I can get statistics for a desired column based on a factor column.

For instance, if I want to know the ratio of Sepal.Width/Sepal.Length per Species, in the iris dataframe, I'd go like this:

```
by(iris$Sepal.Width/iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
iris$Species: setosa
[1] 0.6842483
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] 0.4676804
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] 0.4533956
```

So far so good. Now, the question is, how can I the same but for only a sub-set of levels. e.g *setosa* and *versicolor* only?

I have a complex data.frame with thousands of factors. I am playing a bit with table in order to create sub-sets of factors based on different statistics. I would like to then go back to my original data.frame and create more numbers for my desired sub-set of factors.

Thanks

Comment: There are a large number of methods for this, some of them sketched out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9800266/1036500 You might consider asking another question those shows more of the specific complexity of your actual use-case to get a more useful answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
with( droplevels( subset(iris, Species %in% c("setosa",  "versicolor") ) ), 
     by(Sepal.Width/Sepal.Length, Species, mean) )
```

Comment: +1 -- Even nicer if you wrap the `subset()` call with `droplevels()`.

Comment: Hey, you should write this answer.

Comment: Hah. I was just pleased to see/recall that `droplevels` has a method for entire data.frames.